# Pass single complex type parameter to wcf operation issue

Tags: c#, wcf, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to send one parameter of Complex type to a WCF operation, but when I try to consume it, the signature of the operation become different and be converted to multiple parameters of simple types.

How can I keep the signature at client side as declared in server ?

For Example, My WCF looks like:

```
[MessageContract]
public class Foo
{
    [MessageBodyMember]
    public int ID {get; set;}

    [MessageBodyMember]
    public DateTiem Birthdate {get; set;}

    [MessageBodyMember]
    public string Name {get; set;}
}

[ServiceContract]
public interface IMyService
{

    [OperationContract]
    string Get(Foo request);
}

public class MyService
{
    public string Get(Foo request)
    {
         // My Code
    }
}
```

and the Clint side looks like:

```
MySvc.MyServiceClient c = new MySvc.MyServiceClient();

// The following code does not work
MySvc.Foo req = new MySvc.Foo();
req.Id = 5;
req.Birthdate = DateTiem.Now;
req.Name = "John";
c.Get(req);

//I should pass the parameters like the following since the signature here be different
c.Get(5, DateTime.Now, "John");
```

Comment: Why are you using MessageContract and MessageBodyMember instead of DataContract and DataMember?

Comment: The Clint who will consume the service ask for that. According to his demand he need the SOAP Message in hie own defied custom format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple solutions.

The best would be to compile your contract (data and service) objects into a common client assembly and use that same assembly on both the client and server side (so there's no need to create a service reference at all).

It would also be good to not use message contracts at all, only simple data contracts. Those usually look just like the server side when adding a service reference on the client side.

Finally, if you insist on message contracts (you shouldn't, IMHO), you can ask Visual Studio to generate message contracts on the client side when adding a service reference (there should be a checkbox for that).

Comment: Thank you. unfortunately the consumer use different developing environment. but your last suggestion is prefect, you are right while I am adding the reference, I have to click "Advanced" button, and check the check box "Always generate message contracts".